# How to pass values back to a viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to pass values from viewController B to ViewController A.

For example an user clicks from ViewController A and then navigates to ViewController B.

Now, i want to pass a value from VIewController B to VIewController A.

How can i do that.

In VIewController B

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    AVC *avc=[[AVC alloc] init];

    avc.val =[self.arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

In VIewController A

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.la setTitle:self.val forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: Delegate or blocks can do the job for you. Also you can use unwind segue.

Comment: Can you show me an example. I am new to this

Comment: Ask google about "how to create and use custom delegate in ios". He will defiantly gives you your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Try a google search on "Passing data between View Controllers". This question has been asked and answered literally **hundreds** of times. Here's one example thread from here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score -1):

In your B View controller inside Interface file you should declare delegate methods like :

```
@class AViewController;
@protocol BViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)myData:(NSDictionary*)data;

@end
```

than you should assign delegate instance to A viewcontroller.

```
@implementation AViewController<BViewControllerDelegate>

BViewController *b = [[BViewController alloc] init];
b.delegate = self;
[b myData:@{@"bla":@"bla"}];
@end
```